# Fb.api undefined user

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following problem:

Once the user is logged in facebook if I run the following code:

```
FB.api('/me', function(user) {
      alert(user.name);
});
```

It pops up an alert with "Udefined" written.

But if I change the code in the following way:

```
FB.api( /[MY_REAL_FACEBOOK_ID], function(user) {
      alert(user.name);
});
```

It response in the correct manner.

How it is possible ?
Why '/me' never works ?

Comment: That's straight out of the [API examples](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) too :-/ Can you debugger-break on that line or dump out the object you're getting back?

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer ... I'm completely newbie in the facebook API, I even don't know how to debug the error. I'm suspecting that the error is in the FB.init, but I set it as explained in the facebook documentation: FB.init({appId: [MY_APP_ID], status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be querying "/me" in context of the app rather than the user.  The documentation is not as explicit as it could be, but I've had the same issue.

Are you able to use [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)?

After I have FB.init set up, I make a call to FB.getLoginStatus similar to what is found below.  There might be a better way on how to do this, but it works for me.

Hopefully this helps:

```
 FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {

            if (response.session) {
                // logged in and connected user, someone you know

                graphUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" +         response.session.access_token + "&callback=displayUser"
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.src = graphUrl;
                document.body.appendChild(script);


            } else {
                // no user session available, someone you dont know

            }});


 function displayUser(user) {

        alert(user.name);
    }
```

Comment: It still dosen't work. Why it's necessary the access_token ? The documentation doesn't talk about that. It just tell about the FB.init, the tag FB.login-button and FB.api to require the user's info. Is the access token necessary as well ?

Comment: What is not working?  Are you getting both the response and the session values populated?  To my understanding, the access_token given allows the application you are using to make the permissible calls on the user's behalf.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to overcome the Undefined problem:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : your_app_id,                        
      status     : true,                                 
      xfbml      : true                                 
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            alert("connected");
            connecter=true;
            FB.api('/me', function(user) {
                alert(user.name);
                alert(user.first_name);
                alert(user.last_name);
                alert(user.email);
            });
        } 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks: so what is the fix here? You're testing `response.status === 'connected'` rather than testing whether `response.session` is defined as in the other answer? Is this way better?